# AWS Aurora MySQL multi-reader CPU utilization

Tags: amazon-aurora

I have an Aurora MySQL database with a writer and 3 readers,
My server SQL calls are always done using the Aurora reader endpoint (except writing of course),
For some reason, too often on my app's peak hours, one of the readers will reach 100% cpu usage and the other readers will be around the 10-20% CPU usage, this scenario is causing me serious issues as if I try to make some calls from my app (or any other person for that matter) I will not get a response due to the fact that the reader will not serve me (which is weird since the other 2 are available), I'm not sure if there is something I'm missing regarding the distribution of queries and connections between the different readers, is there any other action required to be done in order to create a better distribution between the readers?
As far as I know, the moment you create multiple readers the reader endpoint should automatically act as a load balancer exactly for this purpose.
If it's of any help, the 3 readers are all db.r3.xlarge.

Comment: You can try with this https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/requests-rds-read-replicas/

Comment: In general, its not measuring any CPU utilization. Work with DNS based round-robin of the cluster reader endpoint